# java replace - replace text in string between two tags that are seperated by spaces and new line

Tags: java, replace

```
String abc = 
"<Message>
    <Details> hello </Details>
</Message>
<Customer>
   <Details> John </Details>
</Customer>
<Bank>
  <Details> BANK1 <Details>
<Bank>"
```

Now I want replace string whatever there between "customer/Details"(here-John) with static text(ex: Peter),  that is replace John with Peter. How to do this in java probably with ReplaceAll function + regular Expression. I dont want to disturb format of string which is in xml format after replacement.
Expected output

```
String abc = 
"<Message>
    <Details> hello </Details>
</Message>
<Customer>
   <Details> Peter</Details>
</Customer>
<Bank>
  <Details> BANK1 <Details>
<Bank>"
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use proper XML tooling?

Comment: Hi and welcome, would you mind posting a [MCVE] of what you tried already?

Comment: I tried something like this. But this will work when there is no \n or \s(newlines and spaces between customer and details tag, but in my case its not like that.  String str = "<Customer><Details>John</Details></Customer>";
        str = str.replaceAll("(<Customer><Details>)[^&]*(</Details></Customer>)", "$1 peter $2");
        System.out.println("replaced String:"+str);

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the whitespace inside the tokens you are recognising:

```
abc.replaceAll("(<Customer>\\s*<Details>)[^<]+(</Details>\\s*</Customer>)", "$1 Fred $2");
```

The `\s` character class recognises all whitespace including `\n`.